# How to send an array from Controller to mailable markdown template and loop it in a table component with Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, email, markdown

I want to send an array (a sort of shopping cart hardcoded) from my Controller to mailable markdown template and loop it in a table component in a way to have several lines containing all my commands.

I send this data from my view with a POST request :

```
commande = {
    "phone":"+213582828193",
    "email":"John@doe.fr",
    "address":"2 rue albert camus",
    "panier": [
        { "name":"Ford", "quantite":"2", "prix":"2000da" },
        { "name":"Ford", "quantite":"2", "prix":"2000da" },
        { "name":"Ford", "quantite":"2", "prix":"2000da" },
        { "name":"Ford", "quantite":"2", "prix":"2000da" },
        { "name":"Ford", "quantite":"2", "prix":"2000da" },
        { "name":"Ford", "quantite":"2", "prix":"2000da" },
    ],
    "total":20
}
```

I receive data to my controller and it display correctly I can access to all data even the $panier array :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $phone = $request->phone;
    $email = $request->email;
    $address = $request->address;
    $panier = $request->panier;
    $total = $request->total;

    $data_panier = [
      'name'=> json_decode($panier['name']) ,
        'quantite'=> $panier['quantite'],
        'prix'=> $panier['prix'],
    ];

    $data = [
        'phone' => $phone,
        'email' => $email,
        'address' => $address,
        'total'=>$total
    ];
    //dd($panier[0]["name"]);

    if ($request){
        //Send Email
        Mail::to($email)->send(new SendInvoice($data, $data_panier));
    }
}
```

My Mailable class where I try to send my $data_panier array :

```
class SendInvoice extends Mailable{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public $data,$data_panier;
public function __construct($data, $data_panier)
{
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->data_panier = $data_panier;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('noreply@mail.com', 'Mailer')->subject('New command')->markdown('mail.send-invoice');
}}
```

An finally my e-mail template where I want to display my $data_panier with all the data inside in a foreach loop but I don't know how and I didn't find documentation or help on how to do that :

```
@component('mail::message')
Introduction

The body of your message.
@component('mail::table')
| Laravel       | Table         | Example  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| --------:|
| {{ $data_panier['name'] }}      | {{ $data_panier['quantite'] }}      | {{ $data_panier['prix'] }}      |
| Col 3 is      | Right-Aligned | $20      |
@endcomponent

@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To traverse through array use blade syntax

```
 <ul>
    @if ( isset( $data_panier ) && is_array( $data_panier ) )
        @foreach ( $data_panier as $data_pan ) --}}
                <li> {{ $data_pan['name'] }} </li>
        @endforeach
    @endif
   </ul>
```

Comment: I can display data on my email template but not an array of data and looping it

Comment: @therealwalim what is the problem with using `@foreach ($alerts as $key)` of blade it should work.

Comment: @therealwalim try using that and let me know if you are still facing any issue, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this

```
    $data = [
        'phone' => $phone,
        'email' => $email,
        'address' => $address,
        'total'=>$total,
        'data_panier' => $data_panier
    ];

    if ($request){
        Mail::to($email)->send(new SendInvoice($data));
    }
}
```

And your mailable class would be

```
public $data;
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you but first It's not working and that's not what I want